# Building server for research team

Tags: linux, python, user-management, graphical-user-interface, gpu

this is kind of a big task for me, I have an engineering background with computer science knowledge but I'm no expert in servers and networking.

I want to build a GPU-enabled computing platform that can be accessed by multiple users simultaneously. The server should be based on Ubuntu. The users should have their dedicated GUI and should be able to develop in Matlab, Python using an IDE for debugging, and other software like 3DSlicer. As for disk usage, there should be a shared space for data used by the whole team and some dedicated space for each user. The users will be engineering students with a wide range of skills, so the easier is the system from a user perspective, the better.

In summary, I would like for all the users to have a user experience like they would be using their workstation, but sharing the resources of a single machine.

Is this approach feasible? Are there any resources to help me understand how to implement such a system? Are there more optimized approaches to deal with such a workload?

Thanks for all the ideas and suggestions that will come up!

Comment: not feasible. I would personally go to AWS cloud and use instance that have GPU. each of your user could have their own VM to work on by themselves and custom to their requirement

Comment: thanks @SharuzzamanAhmatRaslan for answering. AWS cloud unfortunately is not feasible due to budget management limitations. Looking at multiple sources, I was thinking about defining multiple users on the Linux workstation and using xrdp to manage the connections. Could you give me a hint as to why this approach wouldn't be feasible?

Comment: system admin like my is lazy. we want to do 20% work for 80% outcome. customizing the server to handle multiple user is doing 80% work for 20% gain. that is why I said it is not feasible to me

Comment: got it. Any suggestion that might be more cost-effective than AWS while keeping the experience similar to having single VMs for each user?